# Repeatedly extracting substring inbetween specific characters, in a text file (python)

Tags: python, python-re

**I have a several pieces of data stored in a text file. I am trying to extract each type of data into individual lists so that I can plot them/make various figures. There are thousands of values so doing it specifically isn't really an option.
An example of the text file is :**

```
"G4WT7 > interaction in material = MATERIAL
G4WT7 > process PROCESSTYPE
G4WT7 > at position [um] = (x,y,z)
G4WT7 > with energy [keV] = 0.016
G4WT7 > track ID  and parent ID = ,a,b
G4WT7 > with mom dir = (x,y,z)
G4WT7 > number of secondaries= c
G4WT1 > interaction in material = MATERIAL
G4WT1 > process PROCESSTYPE
G4WT1 > at position [um] = (x,y,z)
G4WT1 > with energy [keV] = 0.032
G4WT1 > track ID  and parent ID = ,a,b
G4WT1 > with mom dir = (x,y,z)
G4WT1 > number of secondaries= c"
```

**I would like to extract strings such as the string following "energy [keV] =" so 0.016, 0.032 etc, into a list. I hope to be able to separate all the data similarly to this.**

**So far I've tried to use regex, as following:**

```
import re
file = open('file.txt')
textfile =file.read()
Energy = re.findall('[keV] = ;(.*)G', textfile)
```

**But it just generates an empty list; []
I'm a newbie to python, so apologies if the answer is obvious, and any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to escape the square-brackets!

```
Energy = re.findall('\[keV\] = (.*)', text)
```

... or to be on the save-side you can also use `re.escape` to make sure all characters are properly escaped, e.g.:

```
Energy = re.findall(re.escape('[keV] = ') + '(.*)', text)
```

Comment: The first didn't work for some reason but adding re.escape did! Thank you so much!

Comment: the first one might be os-specific...  you might need to escape the backslash as well... e.g.: `Energy = re.findall('\\[keV\\] = (.*)', text)`    but using `re.escape` is certainly a better idea since it should always take care of properly escaping all reserved characters